React Native Expo Synchronized Video Player (Expo Video Player) with Multi-User Control Causing Looping Play/Pause Issue(firebase)
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { useLocalSearchParams } from "expo-router";
import LoadingIndicator from "@/components/LoadingIndicator";
import useLocalVideoState from "@/hooks/useLocalVideoState";
import { useVideoPlayer, VideoView, VideoViewProps } from "expo-video";
import _ from "lodash"; // For debounce/throttle

export default function SynchronizedVideoPlayer() {
  const params = useLocalSearchParams();
  const { roomId, videoPath } = params;

  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [contentFit, setContentFit] =
    useState<VideoViewProps["contentFit"]>("contain");
  const [videoState, updateVideoState] = useLocalVideoState(roomId as string);
  const [isUpdatingFromServer, setIsUpdatingFromServer] = useState(false);
  const [localPlayState, setLocalPlayState] = useState<boolean>(
    videoState?.isPlaying
  );

  // Initialize player with the video path
  const player = useVideoPlayer(videoPath as string, (player) => {
    player.loop = true;
  });

  // Throttled update function to prevent excessive writes
  const throttledUpdateVideoState = useCallback(
    _.throttle((newVideoState) => {
      updateVideoState(newVideoState);
    }, 500),
    [updateVideoState]
  );

  // Handle play/pause and seek syncing with Firestore
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isUpdatingFromServer) {
      const currentTimeDifference = Math.abs(
        player.currentTime - (videoState.currentTime || 0)
      );

      // Only update if there is a noticeable change in play/pause or time position
      if (videoState.isPlaying !== localPlayState) {
        setLocalPlayState(videoState.isPlaying);
        videoState.isPlaying ? player.play() : player.pause();
      } else if (currentTimeDifference > 1) {
        player.currentTime = videoState.currentTime;
      }
    }
  }, [videoState, player, isUpdatingFromServer]);

  // Handle local user interactions with play/pause to avoid feedback loops
  const handlePlayPauseChange = useCallback(
    (isPlaying: boolean) => {
      setLocalPlayState(isPlaying);
      setIsUpdatingFromServer(true);

      throttledUpdateVideoState({
        isPlaying,
        currentTime: player.currentTime,
      });

      // Remove the update flag after sync to allow further server updates
      setTimeout(() => setIsUpdatingFromServer(false), 500);
    },
    [throttledUpdateVideoState, player]
  );

  // Listen for play/pause changes in the player and sync them with Firestore
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = player.addListener("playingChange", (isPlaying) => {
      handlePlayPauseChange(isPlaying);
    });

    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
    };
  }, [player, handlePlayPauseChange]);

  // Listen for user-initiated seek actions and sync with Firestore
  const handleSeek = useCallback(() => {
    setIsUpdatingFromServer(true);

    throttledUpdateVideoState({
      isPlaying: localPlayState,
      currentTime: player.currentTime,
    });

    setTimeout(() => setIsUpdatingFromServer(false), 500);
  }, [localPlayState, throttledUpdateVideoState, player]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const seekListener = player.addListener("playToEnd", handleSeek);
    return () => {
      seekListener.remove();
    };
  }, [player, handleSeek]);

  // Render loading indicator while the video is loading
  // if (isLoading) return <LoadingIndicator />;

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <VideoView
        ref={ref}
        style={styles.video}
        player={player}
        allowsFullscreen
        allowsPictureInPicture
        contentFit={contentFit}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "#000",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  video: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
  },
});


I am trying to do a player which play video in sync if users have the same file in room. Controls are also synced so if any user play, pause, forward or backward then every user will see changes and player should from there.
I am using a hook to update the videostate so every user can fetch this data. In this page i am fetching videoState in real time using onsnap of firebase. But when 2 or more user play the video or do any action like pause and play then it start flickering. It pause and play in loop. How can i handle this?
